# JSoup and JSF.... I´m loosing my current objects / new session generated

Tags: jsf, jsoup

I´m trying to create a PDF with OpenHtml2PDF which is using also JSoup.
PDF is rendering and is working.

My main problem is, that JSoup will generate a new session but I need the existing one, so I can use the objects, which I´ve already filled.
Furthermore my XHTML must be currently in a public directory, because during JSoup connect it will be generate a new Session, but without any logged in user - so it cannot be in a secured directory (only access for logged in user)

Here I will create the JSoup Document:

```
/**
     * Parsen XHTML
     * 
     * @param urlStr
     * @param timeoutMs
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Document html5ParseDocument(String urlStr, int timeoutMs) throws IOException {
        
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

            String serverName = externalContext.getRequestServerName();
            String port = String.valueOf(externalContext.getRequestServerPort());
            String appName = externalContext.getRequestContextPath();
            String protocol = externalContext.getRequestScheme();

            String jsfPage = "myPage.xhtml";        
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(true);

            String url = protocol + "://" + serverName + ":" + port + appName + "/common/" + jsfPage
                    + ";jsessionid=" + session.getId().toString()
                    + "?documentDesignerId=" + 123456789" 
                    ;

        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc;
              
        
        doc = Jsoup.parse(url, timeoutMs);
        
        // Should reuse W3CDom instance if converting multiple documents.
        return new W3CDom().fromJsoup(doc);
    }
```

The session will be generated in:
doc = Jsoup.parse(url, timeoutMs);

Any idea how I can:
a) Use the existing session with the current objects
b) Same session, so JSoup will not generate a new session, so my XHTML file can be also in a secured directory (only visible for logged in users).

Many thanks for help

Comment: What's the `<session-config>` in your `web.xml`? Does it have `<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>`? If so, then `;jsessionid=` path param indeed won't work.

Comment: It´s:  <session-config>
  <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
  <session-timeout>28800000</session-timeout>
 </session-config> how should I change it?

Comment: Ah you've a `URL` as well. Well, then it's indeed supposed to work fine. You could alternatively try to set an actual cookie in Jsoup instead of using `jsessionid` path parameter. E.g. `Jsoup.connect(url).cookie("JSESSIONID", jsessionid)` etc.

Comment: Is this also valid if I´m using Apache Shiro?

Comment: cookies are set in the HTTP headers. If you have one you need to use, you'll have to manually copy/paste it in. You could potentially reconstruct the login process in JSoup using HTTP requests though and dynamically grab the relevant values to log yourself in and obtain the cookies. Harder to do but possible.